# Authentication issue for recurring subscription Authorize.net

Tags: payment-gateway, magento-1.9, authorize.net, recurring-billing

I am testing Authorize.net as engine to place recurring orders.
I am able to place non-recurring orders successfully with existing authorize.net API credentials but I am getting 'Unable create subscription on Authorize.net: E00007: User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values.' for creating recurring subscription orders.
Can anyone give some pointers regarding this issue?
Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your 'Transaction key' and all given details are correct.